# In rspec/capybara, I need a version of "within" that checks all descendants, not just children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a snippet of code designed to count the number of list items in a dropdown menu:

```
within ('#campaign_duration_in_days_input') do
  page.all('li').count.should eql(4)
end
```

That returns 0, although there are four list items as descendants of that div (not direct children).  How can I get a count of all descendants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. `within` works with indirect descendants as well as direct children. It would also throw an error if the argument `#campaign_duration_in_days_input` so it looks like that element exists.

So looks like it is just not finding any `li` elements. If this is a plain old HTML `select` dropdown should you be looking for `option` elements? If not then try save_and_open_page immediately before the within to inspect the DOM to see what is happening.

Comment: Using save_and_open_page showed me not all of my css loads during tests, meaning there actually were no `li` elements.  Thanks